# How to compute effect size for Friedman's test?

Tags: sas, effect-size, friedman-test

I was looking for a way to compute the effect size for Friedman's test, but could not find any reference. I wanted to see if there is any difference between the groups and what its size was.

I have only two groups to compare. I found [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/whatstat/whatstat.htm) that Friedman's test can be used if the independent variable has two or more levels:

> You perform a Friedman test when you have one within-subjects
>   independent variable with two or more levels and a dependent variable
>   that is not interval and normally distributed (but at least ordinal).

I'm aware that Wilcoxon's test could be used instead. However, I'm interested in calculating the effect size for Friedman at the moment.

Comment: There seem to be a mix of questions here. 1 is how to get an ES for Friedman's test, 2 is how to compute it in SAS. 1 is on topic here, but 2 is not (such questions can be on topic on [SO], though). Please edit to clarify what you are after. Note that you can ask the statistical question here, then ask the coding question on [SO] afterwards, linking to this for context.

Comment: Ok, @gung, I will edit the question. :)

Comment: This page might be of help: http://yatani.jp/teaching/doku.php?id=hcistats:kruskalwallis